# When i try to store data locally or in cookies, its nor working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I was implementing a feature where i want to store data until a midnight. When i am trying to store, there is some latency in data being stored. can someone explain?

#### expected

Basically i want to store the data so then even if user refresh, the data will be stored and once the user completes the game, the user cannot play another round until next day.

#### problem

It is storing data but it stores data on next input. when one input is processed, second input is processed, it stores the data of first input.

#### code

```
const compareInput = useCallback((inputValue) => {
    const guess = PLAYERS.find(player => player.playerName.toLowerCase() === inputValue.toLowerCase());
    // console.log(guess);
    if(!guess) {
        alert("Player not found");
        return;
    }
    if(guess.jerseyNumber === hero[0].jerseyNumber) {
        setplayer1((prevValues) => ({...prevValues, jerseyNumber: guess.jerseyNumber}));
    }
    if(guess.jerseyNumber === hero[1].jerseyNumber) {
        setplayer2((prevValues) => ({...prevValues, jerseyNumber: guess.jerseyNumber}));
    }
    if(guess.jerseyNumber === hero[2].jerseyNumber) {
        setplayer3((prevValues) => ({...prevValues, jerseyNumber: guess.jerseyNumber}));
    }
    if(guess.jerseyNumber === hero[3].jerseyNumber) {
        setplayer4((prevValues) => ({...prevValues, jerseyNumber: guess.jerseyNumber}));
    }
    if(guess.franchise === hero[0].franchise) {
        setplayer1((prevValues) => ({...prevValues, franchise: guess.franchise}));
    }
    if(guess.franchise === hero[1].franchise) {
        setplayer2((prevValues) => ({...prevValues, franchise: guess.franchise}));
    }
    if(guess.franchise === hero[2].franchise) {
        setplayer3((prevValues) => ({...prevValues, franchise: guess.franchise}));
    }
    if(guess.franchise === hero[3].franchise) {
        setplayer4((prevValues) => ({...prevValues, franchise: guess.franchise}));
    }
    if(guess.playerName === hero[0].playerName) {
        setplayer1((prevValues) => ({...prevValues, playerName: guess.playerName}));
        setGuessPlayer1(true);
    }
    if(guess.playerName === hero[1].playerName) {
        setplayer2((prevValues) => ({...prevValues, playerName: guess.playerName}));
        setGuessPlayer2(true);
    }
    if(guess.playerName === hero[2].playerName) {
        setplayer3((prevValues) => ({...prevValues, playerName: guess.playerName}));
        setGuessPlayer3(true);
    }
    if(guess.playerName === hero[3].playerName) {
        setplayer4((prevValues) => ({...prevValues, playerName: guess.playerName}));
        setGuessPlayer4(true);
    }
    localStorage.setItem('player1', JSON.stringify(player1));
    localStorage.setItem('player2', JSON.stringify(player2));
    localStorage.setItem('player3', JSON.stringify(player3));
    localStorage.setItem('player4', JSON.stringify(player4));

}, [hero, inputValue, player1, player2, player3, player4]);
```

Comment: Aside from the issue you have, you really need to spend some time researching the [DRY principle](https://thevaluable.dev/dry-principle-cost-benefit-example/)

Comment: Are you sure that the issue in this part of code?

Comment: i am sure issue is in this part only

Comment: @JayMehta there is a whole lot mess in the code, please fix those bro. Too many if conditions, why dont you set item inside the `if` condition itself instead of moving all those at the end. each time the condition is executed, all the `setItem` will be triggered, which keeps updating storage unnecessary. Use `switch... case` instead of `if`

Comment: @AkhilAravind thank you for suggestion.
i will implemnt DRY principle
but can you please tell me that where does games like wordle store their solution and data?

Comment: @JayMehta you can use redux , context, signals for storing unless you want to persist those on reload

Comment: @AkhilAravind 
Can you share some example?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of your code, or at least what type of variables are the `player1,2,3...` ones, it's just a blind guess, but I will assume that they are created with React's `useState`.

In that case, your problem will be that the state variables are not updated until the next render, that's how React's `setState` works.

In order to have the updated value accessible, you will have to create a temporary variable inside your function.

Take a look at this section of the React docs that describes your problem, in this case logging will be your localStorage write: https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#ive-updated-the-state-but-logging-gives-me-the-old-value